# Checking User Input In Real Time

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my application, when a user is being created, s/he can select their birthdate by choosing a year, a month, and a day in three different drop-downs.

Presently, the user is able to choose a future date as his birth date. I'm in need a way to check if the user is selecting a valid date and warn them in the event the date is invalid.

I know I will need to use some JavaScript but I've never used it in a Rails app before. My main problem is determining how can to access the inputs' value from the JS file.

Thanks in advance.

Code that corresponds to the date selection part in the form:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label "Date of Birth (YYYY-MM-DD)", :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.select :year_Of_Birth , options_for_select((Time.now.year - 100)..(Time.zone.now.year )), :include_blank => true  %>
    <%= f.select :month_Of_Birth, 1..12 , :include_blank=> true  %>
    <%= f.select :day_Of_Birth, 1..31 , :include_blank => true  %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: js runs on the client. just put some `onchange` handlers onto the various fields to trigger the validation.

Comment: How can i acess the inputs on the form from the js file?

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" onchange="validate(this)">`, basically.

Comment: I don't know ruby, but can you add id's into your select boxes?  Then your JavaScript would be very simple like this, `var selectValue = document.getElementById("selectId").value`

Comment: Using what @MarcB suggested, you may want to look into using `onchange` for the `year_Of_Birth` and `month_Of_Birth` elements, and update the options for `day_Of_Birth` to only include valid days. You don't really want a user to have the ability to select an invalid date -- it isn't a good user experience IMO.